# Multicolumn lookup

Tags: excel, indexing, match

There are a lot of posts that relate, but I haven't found one quite like this. I am currently going through excel to help out in speeding up a process a little more. 
The excel file has two spreadsheets. One is data the second is the summary. 
On the data spreadsheet, I have the first column as names, and the next 7 columns with data values (Not all filled).

```
Name     Data1    Data2    Data3   Country    Address
VA       123      456      621     USA        ExampleSt.
MD                123              France     123Street
DC       621                       Korea      999Avenue

UseCol   Value
Data2    456
Data3    621
Data1    000
```

My question is, I am given the value "621" (which can appear in multiple columns, but won't appear in ). I am given which set it should be in "data1, data2, data3...". How would I go about finding the name with that information? No VBA, only through excel.

I got stopped here with this code.

```
=INDEX(A1:D4,MATCH('621',*What do I put here*,0)
```

For that middle section, the reason why it is a problem is because I'm given which data column to use in another spreadsheet.

**EDIT**

So, I have followed what Tim Williams has said about using the offset. However, now I have a second column I am trying to get to. So the code that I used to get the Name is as follows

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A4,MATCH(B7,OFFSET(A2:A4,0,MATCH(A7,B1:D1,0)),0,1),"ERROR")
```

What changes do I have to make to the OFFSET portion to now look for the Country, or the Address cell? I believe the only part I need to change is that inner "MATCH" function. Should I do MATCH(A7,B1:D1,0)+3 to get to Country column? Thank you.

Comment: `621` appears twice in your sample table - will it appear more than once in reality? If so, how can you further determine which Name to return? "...s because I'm given which data column to use in another spreadsheet." So, you'll know which `Data#` column to look in?  Where will that info be?

Comment: What you are asking is next to impossible (and taxed with a **HUGE** calculation lag) unless you can provide the number of columns to examine for **621** as well as an approximation of the rows in the data set. Additionally, should it be read left-to-right to find the first match or from top-to-bottom?

Comment: For my own curiosity, what hybrid clone of Excel are you using that accepts a single tick (e.g. `'`) rather than a double quote (e.g. `"`) to denote text in a formula?

Comment: BruceWayne - The information of which column to use is in another cell.
Jeeped - Since we know which column (because it is told in another cell), it should be read top to bottom I believe. And also, I'm only saying "621", because I didn't want to say values D4 and B2. It would look easier to lookup on this example that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me as long as each number can only appear once per column.

**EDIT**: for getting the matching value from other columns you only need to adjust the first part of the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I am fairly new with excel and do not know much of what "OFFSET" does, so finding that it is useful here really helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, I have a question. Does this only work when the Name col is before the DATA columns? In my actual work, I have a name column that comes before the DATA columns. Then I have a secondary name column that comes after my data columns. When I try to do the same thing (Just switching $A$2:$A$7 to $F$2:$F$7, it gives me an error. What is wrong?

Comment: You would need to adjust the offsets based on the relative column positions.

Comment: I'm looking through a bunch of articles and I'm not really understanding how to use offset. Imma put a more specific example of my excel. Thanks for your help! @Tim Williams. If you look at original post, I'll put up my edits

Comment: YES! That is it!! Thank you so much! I have been struggling with that for a couple days now and finally its working. I will have to read up on "OFFSET" and "INDEX" functions a lot more. Thanks again! @Tim Williams.

Comment: Quick Question, How much harder will it be if all of the data is on a workbook, and all the calculations are on another? (Not different spreadsheet, but completely different file).

Comment: You just need to select the appropriate ranges for your formulas.

Comment: Oh that was easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you are missing is your lookup range in which you are trying to find the row that contains 621. Simply reference the desired column range, or create a named range and reference that.

**WITH A GIVEN RANGE**

I created a named range for the `NAME` column called "NAMERANGE".
I created a named range for the `DATA1` column called "DATA1RANGE".

Using this formula I can retrieve the name if any of the row containing the given value in the given column range:

`=INDEX(NAMERANGE,MATCH(621,DATA1RANGE,0))`

Replace the value, and Data Range as needed.

**WITH A DYNAMIC RANGE**

If you need to dynamically choose the data range, you can use the `INDIRECT()` function to generate a reference to your desired lookup column. For example, in R1C1 style references, to get the DATA3 column, you would use the following formula:

`=INDIRECT("C"&4&")`

So in R1C1 style, given that you want to search in the 2nd data column (which is the third column of the spreadsheet), your formula could be:

`=INDEX(NAMERANGE,MATCH(621,INDIRECT("C"&3),0))`

Comment: Is it possible to do the INDIRECT function with a match? Because The only way I know the column number is by looking at the col.ref. that is in the excel spreadsheet. In other words, to use INDIRECT, I cannot have a random column to choose from. Correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by having a random column to choose from. Using Indirect, you can create whatever reference you need. If you already have the reference, then you don't need the Indirect function. Using indirect, you simply need to build your range string in either A1 or R1C1 notation style depending on which you are using in your sheet.