# Preserve calculation results in an excel sheet, while removing a dependent sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have two Excel workbooks:

One which does calculations (`EXC`),
the other has all of the data values (`EXD`).

`EXC` gathers all of the values from `EXD` and uses formulas to produce new values. When I save the `EXC` file and send it to a friend, he is unable to see the values because he does not have `EXD`, for security reasons.

Is there a way to save the file with all of the calculations completed and preserved in Excel?

I don't want to save it as a PDF file or anything because they need to be edited by the friend.

Will this require VBA?

I am currently using Excel 2010. More information about all the calculations can be found at my other question: [Multicolumn lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025568/multicolumn-lookup). They are not very complex calculations, but necessary.

**SUGGESTION**

If I cannot save it with all the calculations completed:

Is it possible to send him the `EXD` workbook and have it private and not able to be viewed except by `EXC` workbook?

Or

Combine the workbooks together and make one of the spreadsheets hidden to him but viewable for the `EXC` spreadsheet?

Comment: Save a copy of EXD - on each sheet select all the content and *Copy > Paste Special > Paste Values*.

Comment: Is this in a macro? If so you can paste with the .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues. If it's not in a maco, Tim has pointed out the proper way.

Comment: @TimWilliams Is that the only way? We have hundreds of different excel spreadsheets that our team goes through, Im not sure that method is ideal for our given situation.

Comment: @JHizzal Im not sure for macros, all I know is that it is a xlsx file.

Comment: Keep in mind that it is technically possible to hide one sheet in a workbook and make a password required to unhide it. However, that is not a secure method - anyone who knows the method can quite simply remove the internal password created in this way. Therefore it should only used for 'hassle prevention' reasons, and not for actual security/confidentiality reasons.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon is it possible to hide one workbook entirely and have another workbook still read data from it?

Comment: Not in the sense that you mean. To read from a workbook, the workbook file needs to be on the same computer, or on a shared network drive. Either way, the user looking at the output file needs to be able to access the source workbook, otherwise Excel won't be able to access it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go in your EXD workbook. Save as a new file. Go to the Data ribbon, and under the Connections section, click 'Edit Links'. Select all links, and click "break connection". This takes all cells which refer to another file, and converts those cells into values only.

Comment: For that part, the Edit Links part is greyed out. I went in and added the EXC workbook into the EXD connections, but it says that the connections aren't being used anywhere.

Comment: If it's greyed out, that means there's no link. There's something else going on here...

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered well, but I'll just add this tip if it helps anyone.

If you want to convert an individual cell from formula to a static value: Select the cell and hit F2 to alter the formula, but then hit F9 and it will change to the static solution for the formula. Just tab out to another cell and you're done.

Comment: Or just CTRL + C (Copy) then ALT then H then V then V (paste values).

Comment: I like where that is going. Is it possible to change the whole workbook into a static solution?

Comment: Click the little corner cell between "A" and "1" at the top left of your workbook. This selects the whole thing. Then press CTRL + C. Then Alt then H then V then V. Copies all cells into values only.

Comment: Bacon: That is super slick, you should add that to your answer haha.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Yes! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Who do I give credit to? Since this is Isaac Asimov's post, and Grade's comment. (Sorry I'm kind of new to stackoverflow as well)

Comment: Follow your <3, @Sulchan; that is the true guide for all things, including fake internet points relating to Excel queries.

Comment: @Sulchan I've given Bacon the edits to combine his answers. Clearly he gets the credit, so give the credit to his answer haha!

Comment: Well thank you both for helping me out. :) I'm really liking the stackoverflow community already.

Answer (score 1):

Want it all done with one click? This is a macro that can fix the values of all your files according to a path and a pattern name. With one click, you fix all your files, no need to open them yourself and play with the ribbon ;)

```
Sub FixAllValues()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim pattern As String: pattern = "C:\SO\*EXD*.xlsx" ' <~~ put your pattern here
    Dim f As String: f = Dir(pattern)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False: Application.EnableEvents = False
    Do Until f = ""
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(f)
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.UsedRange.Value = ws.UsedRange.Value
        Next
        wb.Close True
        f = Dir
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True: Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```